# Use of "In the following"

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

Is it correct to say:

"In the following, we outline how this can be done".

My main question is that: Is "In the following" at a right place?

Comment: Yes, why would you think it is not?

Comment: @MadWard Thank you for the answer. "why would you think it is not?"--> because the English is not my first language and I was double checking with some experts (like you). :)

Comment: I'm nowhere near an expert, and what I wanted to know is where you would have put it, because merely telling you "it's right" won't get you far!

Comment: @MadWard Please assume that we have designed a protocol (in computer science area) that supports two clients. Now I would like to say that     " with minor adjustment the two-client protocol can be turned into m-client (m>2) protocol. In the following, we outline how this can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can but it is better to say,
In the following [add **subject**, for example: questions, topic, animals, picture, etc...) we will outline how this can be done. 
So it will become something like: In the following **questions**, we will outline how this can be done.

Answer (score 5):

Some other ways to say the same thing:

"The following outlines how this can be done:"

"In what follows, we outline how this can be done."

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "In the following," you could simply say "Next,"

Comment: Welcome to English Language Learners! While this may be correct, we like our answers to be backed up by references. You can [edit] your answer to include one (e.g. an online dictionary, or a relevant similar quote). See the Help Center article [answer].